# Translate JavaScript (d3) to Java

Tags: scala, groovy, clojure, java-8

Yes I know, they have nothing in common beside the name :-) Today I use d3 in a JavaFX webengine server environment. This works well but I am not really happy with the performance and converting Objects to JSObject and back. To make a long story short I am thinking of porting d3 for use in Java.

Since JavaScript uses lambda and clojures I am not sure if I should use a "middleware" - i.e. translate JavaScript to Scala and use the Scale classes in my existing Java Application. And since I am not fimilar with Java 8, Scala, Clojure and Groovy I want you to ask you if this will make the port easier. And which one would be the best choice - in the sense of similar syntactic features.

What do you think will the effort be for a project like d3? I am expecting something around 5  days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy, although having an option to be [statically compiled](http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20), is dynamic by default with a familiar bracket syntax. Of the three, i believe Groovy is the most similar to Javascript. Groovy's metaprogramming is similar to Javascript's prototype, and Groovy has lambdas/closures.

I'm no Javascript guru, but this JS code:

```
function Person(personName) {
  var name = personName;
  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
}

Person.prototype.upperName = function() {
  return this.getName().toUpperCase();
}

var person = new Person("john doe");

console.log(person.upperName()); // prints JOHN DOE
```

Can be written in Groovy using metaprogramming, through `metaClass`, and closures:

```
class Person {
  String name
}

Person.metaClass.upperName = {
  delegate.name.toUpperCase()
}

def person = new Person(name: "john doe")

println person.upperName() // prints JOHN DOE
```

Comment: I will accept this as correct answer since this fits best to the question. But I will give c2 a try, so I upvote this one.

Answer (score 1):

All my recommendations are to use from clojure perspective and as far as I know you can use:

- [C2](https://github.com/lynaghk/c2), "a declarative data visualization in Clojure(Script)" (it has a similar functionality as D3 but done with Clojure Thinking).
- [Quil](https://github.com/quil/quil), "mix [processing.org](http://processing.org/) and clojure"
- [Strokes](https://github.com/dribnet/strokes): "Let's pretend d3 was written in ClojureScript"

Note: ClojureScript is clojure for targeting javascript, so i think C2 and Quil are the better choices although Strokes is the more similar to D3 written in clojure

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint of C2, this really looks promissing!

Comment: Good to hear that, i like C2 too, but i remember  that C2 is not designed to support animation as D3

Comment: I will accept groovy as correct answer since this fits best to the question. But I will give c2 a try, so I upvote this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Java 8/Nashorn? It's said to be several times faster than Rhino-based implementation.

> Sam Pullara, from Twitter, came forward to describe **how painless it
>   was to get Mustache.js up and running (20x over Rhino)**, and,  John
>   Ceccarelli, from NetBeans came forward to describe how Nashorn has
>   become an integral part of Netbeans. [[Nashorn Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/welcome_to_the_nashorn_blog)]

Comment: Sadly Rhino / Nashorn lacks by a missing dom implementation so you have to use something like env.js which is pretty outdated. Or rewirte the whole thing and share Java objects. This is what I have done before, but was not really cool and hard to debug.

Comment: @KIC For both Rhino and Nashorn you have WebKit (`WebView`) in JavaFX 2, so you don't need to emulate the browser. I'm in fact writing an AngularJS desktop app at the moment which is run inside a `WebView`. A simple demo to call JS from Java (vice versa is also possible, in some cases you would need to serialize objects into JSON as it's buggy at the moment in Java 8): [demo](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7481304).

Comment: please see my question, this exactly what I am doing today.

Comment: Yeah, just thought that you were using Rhino and were not aware of Nashorn speed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want javascript on the JVM: [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29).

Javascript is dynamically typed (and somewhat weakly typed).  Clojure is vaguely similar in that regards and has fairly similar concepts, but the syntax, control structures and library apis are different, so would involve some work.

Converting to Scala / Java 8, would possibly take a little longer (if you have complex logic & data structures), since they're statically-typed strongly-typed languages.  Although java does have the advantage of fairly similar language syntax to JS.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried Rhino before I started using JavaFX and not really succeeded.